# PyQGIS render vector layer into .tif?

Tags: pyqgis

How can I render a vector layer into .tif file? I tried with below codes without luck.

PS: I am doing this on ubuntu server and running it via PyQGIS.

**Python scripts**

```
#!/usr/bin/python
from qgis.core import *
from qgis.utils import *
from PyQt4.QtCore import *

def main():
  qgis_prefix="/usr"    
  QgsApplication.setPrefixPath(qgis_prefix, True) 
  QgsApplication.initQgis()
  app = QgsApplication([], False)

  uri = "elevp.csv?delimiter=%s&xField=%s&yField=%s&elevField=%s" % (";","x","y","elev")
  vlayer = QgsVectorLayer(uri, "test", "delimitedtext")

  # create image
  img = QImage(QSize(800, 600), QImage.Format_ARGB32_Premultiplied)

  # set image's background color
  color = QColor(255, 255, 255)
  img.fill(color.rgb())

  # create painter
  p = QPainter()
  p.begin(img)
  p.setRenderHint(QPainter.Antialiasing)

  render = QgsMapRenderer()

  # set layer set
  lst = [vlayer.getLayerID()]
  render.setLayerSet(lst)

  # set extent
  rect = QgsRect(render.fullExtent())
  rect.scale(1.1)
  render.setExtent(rect)

  # set output size
  render.setOutputSize(img.size(), img.logicalDpiX())

  # do the rendering
  render.render(p)

  p.end()

  # save image
  img.save("render.tif","tif")


main()
```

I tried to capture the debug error with [pdb](http://docs.qgis.org/2.0/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/ide_debugging.html#debugging-using-eclipse-and-pydev) and it show as below: -

```
-> /path/to/pyqgis/test.py(40)main()
-> rect = QgsRect(render.fullExtent())
```

Can I also ask if [pdb](http://docs.qgis.org/2.0/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/ide_debugging.html#debugging-using-eclipse-and-pydev) is the correct debugging tool to use?

Comment: Knowing that you "tried ... without luck" is not nearly as helpful to potential answerers as an error message or symptom description.

Comment: there isn't any error message given from pyqgis. How can I grab the error message?

Comment: I'm not one of the potential answerers of this question.  I recommend that you [edit] your question to let them know that because they may not read the comments.  I also recommend these suggestions on how to frame your questions to attract potential answerers: http://meta.gis.stackexchange.com/a/3353/115

Comment: Thanks just tried with pdb debugging message not sure if that is the correct tool. Updated on the post and yet no clear hints given still..

Comment: Which is your operative system? It is an external application of QGIS or are you working at the Python Console?  Where are the features of the layer?

Comment: Sorry @xunilk didn't mentioned it clearly on the descriptions. I am doing it on ubuntu server and develop via PyQGIS.